# Does a portable AC with inverter makes similar level of noise as one without inverter until it reaches target temp?

Tags: air-conditioning

I bought a portable AC with dual inverter technology after hearing that it makes less noise than one without inverter technology.

I was surprised that it is actually very noisy. It makes more noise than my previous one.

It sounds like a portable AC with an inverter works very hard until it reaches the target temperature and then slows down to use less energy and make less noise.

So the bottom line is that a portable AC with an inverter makes less noise than one without an inverter ONLY when it reached its target temperature.

Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Perhaps noise is related to yhe AC cycle.

Comment: Portables are fighting venting through a hose, which makes the fan's job difficult. They are also often asked to try to cool more space than they can reasonably be expected to. I suspect there's considerable variation between different examples, which may or may not track well with having inverter drive (can vary speed) if that alone, rather than overall quality of design/construction is the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverter allows the A/C compressor or fan to run at more than one speed, automatically. Lower speeds are quieter. But when full speed is needed to quickly cool the room, the noise will not be improved by an inverter.

Comment: Thank you. Sounds like I understood it correctly.